# iOS, url schemes for app store both for specified developer's apps and for his concrete app to update in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, ios6, app-store, url-scheme

This question was already answered but in iOS 6 all these solutions doesn't work.
My current solutions sometimes doesn't work too:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/developer_name/developer_id

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app_name/app_id

the problem is in iOS 6.0.1, but no error with iOS 6.1

Comment: Please check my answer, it works for iOS 5,6& 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my end (Xcode 5 - iOS 7 - **Device**!):

1. For the **app** itself:

   ```
   itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/idYOUR_APP_ID
   ```

   Code snippet (you can just copy& paste it):

   ```
   #define YOUR_APP_STORE_ID 545174222 // Change this to your app ID

   static NSString *const iOS7AppStoreURLFormat = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@";
   [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: iOS7AppStoreURLFormat, YOUR_APP_STORE_ID]]; // Would contain the right link
   ```
2. For the **developer** you can use this:

   ```
   https://itunes.apple.com/artist/idYOUR_ARTIST_ID
   ```

You can get YOUR_ARTIST_ID from your iTunes Connect or from the link on one of your apps (there is a "View more by this developer" and copy the number after the "id" on the link itself).